# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 413: Payload Too Large

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping a variety of pages (`the_url`) within a large website using the following code:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()

url = opener.open(the_url)

contents_of_webpage = url.read()
url.close()

contents_of_webpage = contents_of_webpage.decode("utf-8")
```

This works fine for almost every page but occasionally I get:
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 413: Payload Too Large

Looking for solutions I come up against answers of the form: well a web server may choose to give this as a response... as if there was nothing to be done - but all of my browsers can read the page without problem and presumably my browsers should be making the same kind of request. So surely there exists some kind of solution... For example can you ask for a web page a little bit at a time to avoid a large payload?

Answer (score 0):

It depends heavily on the site and the URL you're requesting. To avoid your problem, most sites/APIs offer pagination on their endpoints. Try to check if the endpoint you're requesting accepts GET parameters like `?offset=<int>&limit=<int>` or smth.

UPD: besides that, `urllib` is not so good in emulating browser behavior.
So you could try making the same request using `requests`, or setting the `User-Agent` header your browser has.

Comment: None of the pages are giving error 413 right now but I will try your suggestions as soon as I get the error again.